# Attachments under File system vs databases?

Tags: java, database, filesystems

I  need to sore attachments at server side. I can store them either under blob column of database or under file directory.
My question is which one is more reliable, scalable and maintainable?

**EDIT:-**

if we go for file system, we have to handle synchroniztion yourself. Is n't it ? For example if two users are trying to create/update the File under same directory how will we handle concurrency with filesystem?

Comment: Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing data in directory is more reliable due to indexing and data fetch and other operation. Just store the path of the file into DB and store that file into directory.

When there's lot's of data store request came on server it's very hard and complex to handle so much request.
So it's better to store data on directory so accessing of data becomes more faster and when the daily scale of DB storage increase then these become so important so when you start any system first of all study it well and then decide that what to do or which technique will be the best ?
When more data are there in DB then clustering and indexing become more important.

If you want to use it for small data storage then blob it good option but for large data I ll not recommend you because I have made online data store web application and faced this situation so at end I have used to store data in directory and just path in DB.

Comment: But if you go for file system, you have to handle synchroniztion yourself. Is n't it ? For example if two users are trying to create/update the File under same directory how will you handle concurrency with filesystem?

Comment: Then you will have to use some kind of temp directory, if java then it provide facility for that and possible then use 2 name for file in DB one is user uploaded and second one is new generated aliased name using which you ll have to store file using new name because to avoid the file overwrite and other thing so when you generate the new file or name then use timestamp plus other uniqueness facility, in my system I have used this method and works well.

Comment: You mean to say that first create the file under file system. Then create the entry under database with file path. If however, exception occurs during db transaction, delete file as well. Right?

Comment: You also said "Storing data in directory is more reliable due to indexing ", do you mean content based indexing here?

Comment: Yes put some field like upload status or something like that when upload complete that field will become true or say 1 or you can do something like that store file size into db when upload start and when download complete check size of uploaded file and DB entry when matches status will be 1 and yes I am telling about storing path of the file and one thing keep in mind to design structure of directory like some year wise of user wise, as you want. yes content based indexing because we can store them separately using some good technique and make faster indexing.